# Reshaping django data grouping them by a foreignkey

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following data in the format of :

```
[ {
    "sales_project_id": 1,
    "sales_project_est_rev": "892123.00",
    "project_status": 1,
    "userProfile": [
        1
    ],
    "customer_information": [
        1
    ]
},

     {
    "sales_project_id": 2,
    "sales_project_est_rev": "892123.00",
    "project_status": 2,
    "userProfile": [
        1
    ],
    "customer_information": [
        1
    ]
}]
```

However i wish to group them together by their `project_status` ID it such that:

```
    [ {
    "project_status": 1
     "data" : [{ "sales_project_id": 1,
                 "sales_project_est_rev": "892123.00",
                 "userProfile": [
                         1
                                ],
                 "customer_information": [
                  1
                  ]
              }]
}]
```

My serializer is as shown below:

```
class SalesProjectAllSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = SalesProject
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 2
```

## EDIT:

Here is what i have done so far :

```
class SalesProjectListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
 def to_representation(self, data):
    ####some code here to get the id of states which will be stored as state_ids
    iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
    return {
              state: super().to_representation(SalesProject.objects.filter(project_status=state))
              for state in State.objects.filter(pk__in=state_ids)
            }
```

class SalesProjectAllSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = SalesProjectListSerializer

However im geting this error :

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

## Edit 2

Here's the changes i have made to my serializers :

```
class SalesProjectListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

 def to_representation(self, data):

    iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
    #Bunch of code here to obtain the id of the states , which will be stored as state_id#

    return {
              state.id : super(SalesProjectListSerializer,self).to_representation(iterable.filter(project_status=state))
              for state in State.objects.filter(pk__in=state_ids)
            }


class SalesProjectAllSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesProject
        fields = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = SalesProjectListSerializer
```

My views.py

```
class SalesProjectAllView(ListAPIView):
queryset = SalesProject.objects.all()
serializer_class = SalesProjectAllSerializer
```

And the data im recieving via post man :

```
[
"1"   #<--- the data is only showing the state.id , and none of the data related to the projects which i require
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super):

> The zero argument form only works inside a class definition, as the compiler fills in the necessary details to correctly retrieve the class being defined, as well as accessing the current instance for ordinary methods.

While technically its part of a method, its context is a dictionary comprehension and I suspect this messes things up. So use the two argument form here.

Comment: hey! i managed to solve the error im recieving above , by putting the SalesProjectListSerializer and self within the super parenthesis ,however im still unable to get the results im hoping for , do you have a clue on how to restructure and group my data ?

Comment: Nope, cause you're not showing what you are getting so we can't compare. You also don't show the models and subserializers if any involved (if any).

Comment: Hey , so sorry about that i forgot to update the question , i have done so now